# Wrong Java version when deploying on heroku

Tags: java, gradle, heroku, deployment

I build a little rest service to store data in a mongodb atlas db.
Everything is working and I get no errors when I build with ./gradlew clean build.

The project is written in Java 11 and gradle is set to Java 11 too.
But when I try do deploy the app on heroku I get the following error :

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Spring Boot detected
-----> Installing **JDK 1.8**... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew build -x check
       Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.2-bin.zip
       ...........10%...........20%...........30%...........40%...........50%...........60%...........70%...........80%...........90%...........100%
       To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
       Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 
       > Task :compileJava FAILED
       
       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
       
       * What went wrong:
       Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
       > invalid source release: 11
```

I added a system.properties to my resources with :
java.runtime.version=11

But it still seems to install java 8.

Can anyone help me on this?

Greetings from Berlin
Nino

Comment: Hey, i have same issue.  Do you find solution?

Comment: I just found that you can deploy app to heroku without git. Instead you can use gradle and heroku plugin for it https://github.com/heroku/heroku-gradle

Comment: I was finally able to deploy war file to heroku with appropriate java version.
In terminal: heroku deploy:war <path to your .war file> --app <your app name> --jdk 11

Comment: thanks alot! going to try it later this day

Answer (score 1):

here are few steps:

1. pres `ctrl+alt+s` and verify your project sdk version
2. goto root of your project where build.gradle and setting.gradle files are present
3. here create a new file name system.properties(this file is dettected for deploying Heroku apps to override default propeties)
4. in this newly created file write this piece of line `java.runtime.version=17.0.5` or what  ever jdk version you want to deploy with..
5. update the repo with this file using `add.`' '`commit`' and `git push heroku master`
   thats all :)